# The asType does not work in Pandas to int64?

Tags: pandas

I try to convert columns type to int64:

```
new_df.astype({'NUM': 'int64'})
```

Afetr `df.info()` I see this:

```
 0   NUM      10 non-null     object
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

The type casting is not done in-place, `DataFrame.astype` returns a new DataFrame with the correct types. So you have to reassign the result to `new_df`.

```
new_df = new_df.astype({'NUM': 'int64'})

print(new_df.info())
```